# How can i use web based code and real button in the same code?

Tags: arduino

I wrote a code in the Arduino IDE. With this code, i can control 4 leds on and off from the web page. In the web page 9 buttons.

2 buttons for led-1 on and off.
2 buttons for led-2 on and off.
2 buttons for led-3 on and off.
2 buttons for led-4 on and off.
1 button for toggle all leds on and off.

I want also add a real button to the circuit. When i press this button, i want to run that toggle code. How can i do that?

This is my code;

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "UnderSpeed";
const char* password = "q1w2e3r4t5__";
const char* host = "192.168.1.185"; //it will tell you the IP once it starts up
                                        //just write it here afterwards and upload
int r0 = D0;
int r1 = D1;
int r2 = D2;
int r3 = D3;
int btn0 = D5;

WiFiServer server(301); //just pick any port number you like

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  // prepare GPIO2
  pinMode(r0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(btn0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(r0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(r1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(r2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(r3, HIGH);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected

  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  while (!client.available()) {
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  client.flush();

  // Match the request
  if (req.indexOf("") != -10) {  //checks if you're on the main page

    if (req.indexOf("/r0-OFF") != -1) { //checks if you clicked OFF
      digitalWrite(r0, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Relay-0 OFF");
    }
    if (req.indexOf("/r0-ON") != -1) { //checks if you clicked ON
      digitalWrite(r0, LOW);
      Serial.println("Relay-0 ON");
    }

    if (req.indexOf("/r1-OFF") != -1) { //checks if you clicked OFF
      digitalWrite(r1, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Relay-1 OFF");
    }
    if (req.indexOf("/r1-ON") != -1) { //checks if you clicked ON
      digitalWrite(r1, LOW);
      Serial.println("Relay-1 ON");
    }

    if (req.indexOf("/r2-OFF") != -1) { //checks if you clicked OFF
      digitalWrite(r2, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Relay-2 OFF");
    }
    if (req.indexOf("/r2-ON") != -1) { //checks if you clicked ON
      digitalWrite(r2, LOW);
      Serial.println("Relay-2 ON");
    }

    if (req.indexOf("/r3-OFF") != -1) { //checks if you clicked OFF
      digitalWrite(r3, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Relay-3 OFF");
    }
    if (req.indexOf("/r3-ON") != -1) { //checks if you clicked ON
      digitalWrite(r3, LOW);
      Serial.println("Relay-3 ON");
    }

    if (req.indexOf("/btn0") != -1) { //checks if you clicked OFF
      buton_islemi();
    }

  }

  else {
    Serial.println("invalid request");
   client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Prepare the response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
  s += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
  s += "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\n";

  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly0-on\" value=\"Relay-0 ON \" onclick=\"location.href='/r0-ON'\">";
  s += "<br>";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly0-off\" value=\"Relay-0 OFF\" onclick=\"location.href='/r0-OFF'\">";

  s += "<br><br><br>";

  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly1-on\" value=\"Relay-1 ON \" onclick=\"location.href='/r1-ON'\">";
  s += "<br>";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly1-off\" value=\"Relay-1 OFF\" onclick=\"location.href='/r1-OFF'\">";

  s += "<br><br><br>";

  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly2-on\" value=\"Relay-2 ON \" onclick=\"location.href='/r2-ON'\">";
  s += "<br>";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly2-off\" value=\"Relay-2 OFF\" onclick=\"location.href='/r2-OFF'\">";

  s += "<br><br><br>";

  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly3-on\" value=\"Relay-3 ON \" onclick=\"location.href='/r3-ON'\">";
  s += "<br>";
  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"rly3-off\" value=\"Relay-3 OFF\" onclick=\"location.href='/r3-OFF'\">";

  s += "<br><br><br>";

  s += "<br><input type=\"button\" name=\"btn0\" value=\"Button-0 \" onclick=\"location.href='/btn0'\">";
  s += "<br>";

  s += "</html>\n";

  client.flush();


  // Send the response to the client
  client.print(s);
  delay(1);  
}

void buton_islemi() {
  digitalWrite(r0, !digitalRead(r0));
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(r1, !digitalRead(r1));
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(r2, !digitalRead(r2));
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(r3, !digitalRead(r3));
  Serial.println("Button Pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int button = 2;
int d = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
d = digitalRead(button);  // read input value
  if (d == LOW) {
 // your web server code
}
else {
Serial.print("Press the button to togggle led's");
}
}
```